# The best way to let asp.net fire events and methods automatically -according to a schedule-

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms, scheduled-tasks

Well, I'm sure this is not the first time to see this question. and TBH you can find this question answered on many other websites and blogs -not only here-

But I never saw a complete answer for this question, I mean no one talked about the advantages and the disadvantages. no one shared a real experience.

Although [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) seems like a good solution but yet, there's no enough reviews or a good comparison between the different ways to achieve such a thing.

As far as I read about it I found this are the possible ways of doing this :

Using a:  Web Service, Windows Appliction, Console Application, Quartz.NET.

Examples of stuff I want to achieve with the scheduled or automatic methods/events are like archiving after a certain period, auto deleting/moving records in the database, setting a property of an object after a certain time, automatically run some methods according to my holiday schedule.

I hope you'd share your experience either with one of those approaches or share a new way of doing this.

Comment: Your title and question do not relate well.  its quite confusing.  Do you want to know all methods of scheduling tasks to run and the positives negatives of each?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, I think he wants to know the best way to pass off events to "something" on a schedule from an ASP.NET application.  Something that might traditionally be solved by a windows service/background timers, etc.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey- hmm, well I was hoping for some clarifications...my main goal is to know the best ways to do the tasks in the examples. If you think there's a major difference please some enlightenment would be appreciated!

Comment: @Moo-Juice- Actually I just read too many questions and it was vague because the real experience lacked. the answer was just a suggestion and it was not even a complete reference on what are the good and the bad sides of each method. btw I was hoping that if doing this within my web application will be efficient, Then I don't want windows stuff involved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the e-commerce Web site that I work for, we use Quartz.NET in a Windows service called the "Worker". It executes Quartz.NET `IJob` implementations via the programmatically-defined schedule and runs independently of the Web site processes. It does things like dispatch e-mails in batches, update statistics, refresh the SOLR indexes, and so on.

This way, we don't have to worry about our schedules getting reset or missed as a result of worker processes recycling, or dealing with the madness of having multiple instances running simultaneously on the same machine as a result of a Web garden. The Worker is installed, started, and stopped independently of the Web site, and could even exist on a separate machine, giving flexibility in maintenance and deployment.

The Web site and the Worker both share a common Model DLL that contains the object model and NHibernate configuration, so there is not much logical duplication of business logic.

Before I created the Worker/Windows service, I relied on simple console applications that were executed via scheduled tasks. This worked well up to a point, but as the site became more complex and required more and more batch jobs to run periodically, I found myself maintaining a lot of independent console programs and a lot of independent scheduled tasks, which became more difficult as the number of jobs required increased. By consolidating scheduling with Quartz.NET into a single Windows service, I now only have one process to keep an eye on and can be assured that any business logic changes are "in sync" since the model only has to be updated in two places--the Worker and the Web site--instead of many--the Web site and lots of little console applications.

I explored options like storing runtimes in the ASP.NET cache or keeping references around in the worker process's memory, but I found that (1) this made the exact execution time of the task dependent on incoming requests to the Web site and (2) the use of a Web garden caused unnecessary duplication of effort (since the task would be "scheduled" in multiple worker processes on the same machine).

Creating a Windows service that can be started and stopped via the usual Windows mechanisms has proved to be, in my humble opinion, the most logical, intuitive, and maintainable result in the long run.

Both the Web site and Worker use WiX to compile down to two Windows Installer MSI files, so updating them is a snap--just double-click the MSI on the server, and our update is good to go.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 Impressive experience. but I have to be honest it's above my experience level and advanced to just start up my own windows service and configure my ORM, etc. This would be a great solution and I like the real experience. but do I have to the service on my machine or what -I'll use an ordinary shared hosting account for my web application- so !?    and that's seems like a lot of work to do, did you blog or find some blog posts about your approach that I could learn from ?

Comment: So far this is the best answer for my question..I hope u could help with the questions in my comments. Thanks

Comment: (1) Does it really have to be shared hosting? VPS is so stupid cheap these days that the flexibility that comes with controlling your own OS with all the services is a no-brainer in many cases. (2) If it has to be shared hosting, then the service would have to run on your machine and connect to your database remotely (likely not allowed in shared hosting). (3) If your shared host lets you do a cron job, you could have it ping a special page of your site on a schedule that does the actual work, eschewing Quartz.NET for a slightly more Rube Goldberg but still workable approach. HTH

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem will be that a web application is intended as a request-response service. So, although probably hackable (and surely people have), you would need to respond to a request in order to kick off some sort of processing task. I know you want a webforms solution, but I would suggest this type of problem domain is not best solved with a web platform.

As a suggestion, although maybe not one you wanted to hear, you could of course use a Windows Service solution and all the good things that go with that platform (background timers, MSMQ processing, threading, easier security integration, etc) and surface it's information via a web based UI application (connected via WCF).

Comment: @Reddog- As far as I read, I think the windows service solution is the best. but in your opinion, don't you think it's a bit much to learn WCF and using the background timers, etc so I could add this one little functionality to a website ? and where could I host this windows service ?....btw do you have any thoughts about Quartz.NET or using a web service instead of a windows service ?

Comment: You could host the webservice where you want really. Probably on the web service as an obvious location if it's just a small one. Also, a webservice is still a request-response model so you still need something requesting in order to kick it off. If this is for just a "little functionality" then maybe a windows scheduled task kicking off a console app is good enough. Then, if you even need UI on top of that, then you could read from log/XML/database files that are known to both your console app and web app.

Comment: I have not worked with Quartz.NET. But if you like it's demos and documentation and you can clearly see it fitting into your system then sure, go for it. Though my immediate reaction to their statement on the home page "targets framework version 1.1" would entice me to look elsewhere.

Comment: @Reddog- Thank you for your help +1. but about the framework version they are targeting "currently targets Framework version 1.1 and above" I think they are trying to say the minimum version is 1.1 and they are trying to be up to date as this is a general description for the tool, you should check the 1.0.3 release news piece. one last thing! if you have any resources where I could learn how to do this that would be great -blog posts, websites, anything-

Comment: I like CodeProject, but of course Google, the omnipotent one, knows all - http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22Windows+Service%22+site:codeproject.com

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following question that was asking something similar:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243400/how-to-do-background-processing-similar-to-that-on-stackoverflow/

I linked to a blog post by [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) himself that had a unique approach to accomplish this:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

I am not endorsing this approach but it's a good alternative if you don't want to make a service or use another tool.

Comment: I've read this one before, but sounds too risky!  btw I don't mind using other tools but I want them to be web based, I don't want to dedicate a machine to serve my website. but maybe Quartz.NET or a web service would help, what do you think ?

Comment: @ IKashef You could do the work in a seperate web service but just use the above method to trigger it. At least you don't have it all wrapped in your application then.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this question asked in at least a 100 ways.  In my experience the best way to go about scheduling is to start with a well thought out n-tier design.  This allows you the flexibility to change out front ends as needed.  For example, a console application to call Method1() which is handled by the windows task scheduler.  I firmly suggest you stick to the windows task scheduler unless requirements drive you to do otherwise.

Timer's are a great idea, in concept.  In execution they can be buggy or simply not function whatsoever depending on the environment (some timers don't work in win services).

As far as a Windows Application, I have never used this for a scheduled task (outside of compiling a console app as a winform app so the console window won't display).  As it displays unecessary UI, confusing the user.

On the DB side you have new options like jobs and Triggers.

In summary, there is no silver bullet.  I suggest you default to a console app and refactor your code so you have a nice design.  Read a design pattern book if you need to.

Comment: Well, I really know how frequently this question is asked but I needed some further follow up questions and the questions are almost old so no one answers me! Anyway, my application is built using 3 layers (DAL uses ADO.NET and pure sql - BLL - PL that uses ODS to consume the BLL layer). I'll need an UI interface that will be associated to my web application since I'll need to add/remove/edit jobs. I very frustrating question >> I'm hosting my website on a shared hosting. where can I host this windows service or application ? any simple example code or tutorials ?

Comment: With a third party hosting company in the picture, we can assume services, and installed applications are going to be disallowed. But, you can call them to be sure.  Timers may well be your only option. I would start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx